# Code permissions evaluation within fully trusted assembly fails

Tags: c#, .net, sandbox, code-access-security

I wanted to use reflection from my 'sandboxed' class *Worker* and caught behavior i cant propertly explain.

- If I dont add current assembly in FullTrustList while creating
  appdomain, then code runs ok.
- If I add current assembly in FullTrustList, then
  PropertyInfo.GetValue throws SecurityException. It requires full
  trust, but within appdomain i have limited pemission sets.

Problem can be solved with PermissionSet.Assert(), but it looks like dirty hack to me.

Does anyone know why the code permissions evaluation is different in both cases?

```
public static class Security
{
    public static void Fail()
    {
        var name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var appSetup = new AppDomainSetup
            {
                ApplicationName = name,
                ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase
            };

        // add permissions
        var permissions = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
        permissions.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
        permissions.AddPermission(new ReflectionPermission(ReflectionPermissionFlag.MemberAccess));
        permissions.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

        var type = typeof(Worker);
        // get strong name to add assembly in full-trusted
        var sn1 = type.Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();

        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(name, null, appSetup, permissions, sn1);
        var worker = (Worker) Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(domain,
                                                           type.Assembly.ManifestModule
                                                                          .FullyQualifiedName,
                                                           type.FullName).Unwrap();
        try
        {
            worker.TryReflect();
        }
        catch (SecurityException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private class Worker : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public static int Prop1 { get; private set; }

        public void TryReflect()
        {
            var prop = typeof (Worker).GetProperty("Prop1");
            // exception is thrown here:
            var val = prop.GetValue(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample is here https://www.sendspace.com/file/svdzhk